# AEM error on real time

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, adobe, aem

Is there a way to configure AEM into an IDE like IntelliJ,Eclipse...
So that the IDE shows the errors on my project before I compile it even if I put it outside the source folder like for example the components created.

If possible both the .java and .jsp

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by outside the source folder, but have you taken a look at adobe's documentation?

They have instructions for IntelliJ + AEM with Maven.  It also instruct on jsp support as well.  It's for 5.6.1 but it should be valid for 6.x as well.
https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/developing/developmenttools/howto-develop-aem-projects-with-intellij.html

Here's one for Eclipse
https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/creating-aem-project-using-eclipse.html

They also have a more generic set of instruction
https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/developing/developmenttools/how-to-build-aem-projects-using-apache-maven.html#How-To%20Work%20with%20JSPs

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can maintain CRX data(AEM folders like /etc, /apps, /content, etc) in an IDE like eclipse. This will help you iron out all the compilation errors using features of IDE. Make use of this eclipse plugin called vaultclipse. You can install it from eclipse marketplace.
There is also another plugin called AEM plugin, details on how to use it [here](http://adobeaemclub.com/aem-eclipse-plugin-setup-tutorial/).